# mathematical function for paths on a grid with specifically allowed movements

Tags: combinatorics, functions, graph-theory

The problem states that on a $n \times n $ grid, calculate the possible paths from the bottom of the grid to top, using only three valid movements:

- Forward or North $\uparrow $
- Top left or North-West $ \nwarrow $
- Top right or North-East $ \nearrow $

And each path is counted when we reach the top.

For example a $ 2 \times 2 $ grid contains $4$ possible paths and a $ 3\times3$ grid contains $17$ possible paths.

Now I have coded the solution to this problem, but I am trying to find a mathematical function to compute the last result without counting the paths by hand or in a computer.

I tried to induct a solution by using simple examples, like a $3\times1$ grid which only has $1$ path using the North movement and any $2\times n$ grid can be computed via: $( 2 \times n ) + ( n - 2 )$ . But on continuing this induction, I hit a brick wall. I also tried using graph theory but could not find anything suitable.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Label each point of the $n \times n$ grid by the number of paths that start at the bottom of the grid and end at that point. We will construct this labeling by induction.

We begin by being able to label each point along the bottom by $1$, since there is one path that starts at that point, does nothing, and ends there.

For other points, the label on each point is the sum of the three labels below it: each path to $(x,y)$ gets there either from $(x-1,y-1)$ or from $(x,y-1)$ or from $(x+1,y-1)$. Of course, for points on the edge of the grid, some of these may not be a possibility.

Letting $\mathbf v(y)$ be the vector of labels on the points $(0,y), (1,y), \dots, (n-1,y)$, this gives us the recursive rule
$$ \mathbf v(y+1) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\end{bmatrix} \mathbf v(y)$$
where the $n\times n$ matrix has a $1$ on the main diagonal and the diagonals immediately above and below it, and zeroes everywhere else.

Let this matrix be $\mathbf A$, and let $\mathbf j$ be the vector of all ones. Then $\mathbf v(0) = \mathbf j$, the recursion $\mathbf v(y+1) = \mathbf A \mathbf v(y)$ tells us that $\mathbf v(n-1) = \mathbf A^{n-1} \mathbf j$, and we can take the sum of the entries of this vector by taking $\mathbf j^{\mathsf T}\mathbf A^{n-1} \mathbf j$.

So this expression $\mathbf j^{\mathsf T}\mathbf A^{n-1} \mathbf j$ is your final answer. It's not as nice as a closed form, but might be the best we can do.

Looking up the first few terms of the $n \times n$ sequence in OEIS, we get [sequence A081113](http://oeis.org/A081113), with some conjectured recurrence relations, and an asymptotic growth rate of $\Theta(n \cdot 3^n)$.